# display single column in list view with two groups

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, grouping

i have customer table  have columns with

```
                                      customer id
                                     customer name
```

I have another table called address 
                                        addressid 
                                        addresstext

now i want to display the customer name and addresstext like this

```
                    customers
                    -----------
                    customer name 1
                    customer name 2
                    customer name 3

                    addresses 
                    -----------
                    addresstext 1
                    addresstext 2
                    addresstext 3
```

like this in list view only single column  above figure[image]

would any one pls help on this..

I am using c# in winforms applications

Comment: would any one pls helop on this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many Thanks For all your support and i have solved my problem ........like this

```
    lstviewcategories.View = View.Details; 
    lstviewcategories.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader() { Width = lstviewcategories.Width - 20 }); 
    lstviewcategories.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None; 
    lstviewcategories.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending; 
    lstviewcategories.Dock = DockStyle.None; 

    ListViewGroup categorygroup = new ListViewGroup("Category Types",HorizontalAlignment.Center); 
    lstviewcategories.Groups.Add(categorygroup); 


    var categorytypes = (from categories in abc.categories 
                         select categories.category_Name).ToList(); 

    lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "ALL", Group = categorygroup }); 
    foreach (string item in categorytypes) 
    { 

        lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = item.ToString(), Group = categorygroup }); 

    } 

    ListViewGroup pricerangegroup = new ListViewGroup("Price Ranges", HorizontalAlignment.Center); 
    lstviewcategories.Groups.Add(pricerangegroup); 

    lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "ALL", Group = pricerangegroup }); 
    lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "0-500", Group = pricerangegroup }); 
    lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "500-1000", Group = pricerangegroup }); 
    lstviewcategories.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = "1000+", Group = pricerangegroup });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to to create a foreign key on your address table that pointed to the customer id.

Comment: is it possible just display the address names and customer name from two different tables.... just display the items in list view with two groups...

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to populate the list view with the data from the sql table then have a look at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/2725cfac-76a0-42f3-90b2-93c6ab96d901/